# My query parameters are not being detected

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routing

I am trying to write an Angular app that loads a different login page based on the "groupId" that I set in the URL. The idea is to send each client a URL that contains a particular "groupId" as a parameter. A template is used to load the page where the page's text and pictures are pulled from the firebase repo using that specific company's groupId.

I tried using query params as follows:

(In my component):

```
  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('test');

    console.log(this.activeRoute.queryParams);
     this.activeRoute.queryParams
    .subscribe(params => {
      this.groupId = params.groupId;
   })
   console.log(this.groupId);
   if (this.groupId === undefined) {
    this.router.navigate(['/login/locked']);
   }
  }
```

(and my routes in the parent component):

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'login',
    component: LoginComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '', component: SignInComponent,
      },
      {
        path: 'signup', component: SignUpComponent,
      },
      {
        path: 'locked', component: LockScreenComponent,
      },
      {
        path: 'password-rest', component: PasswordResetComponent,
      }
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AuthPagesRoutingModule { }
```

However, I keep on getting an `undefined` from the `console.log(this.groupId)` when I paste `www.example.com/login?groupId=FACEBOOK235` into the search bar (and thereby navigating me to the locked screen).

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because your if condition is outside subscribe the queryParams observables is asyncronous. your code should be :-

```
ngOnInit() {
    console.log('test');

    console.log(this.activeRoute.queryParams);
     this.activeRoute.queryParams
    .subscribe(params => {
      this.groupId = params.groupId;
      console.log(this.groupId);
      if (this.groupId === undefined) {
       this.router.navigate(['/login/locked']);
      }
   })
  }
```

(EDIT) When I log the complete parameter list I get:

```
closed: false
destination: BehaviorSubject {_isScalar: false, observers: Array(0), closed: false, isStopped: false, hasError: false, …}
hasError: false
isStopped: false
observers: []
operator: MapOperator {thisArg: undefined, project: ƒ}
source: BehaviorSubject {_isScalar: false, observers: Array(0), closed: false, isStopped: false, hasError: false, …}
thrownError: null
_isScalar: false
[[Prototype]]: Subject
complete: ƒ complete()
constructor: class AnonymousSubject
error: ƒ error(err)
next: ƒ next(value)
_subscribe: ƒ _subscribe(subscriber)
[[Prototype]]: Observable
asObservable: ƒ asObservable()
complete: ƒ complete()
constructor: class Subject
error: ƒ error(err)
lift: ƒ lift(operator)
next: ƒ next(value)
unsubscribe: ƒ unsubscribe()
_subscribe: ƒ _subscribe(subscriber)
_trySubscribe: ƒ _trySubscribe(subscriber)
Symbol(rxSubscriber): ƒ [_internal_symbol_rxSubscriber__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.rxSubscriber]()
[[Prototype]]: Object
```

Comment: Just a correction, this particular observable is asynchronous, but not all observables are asynchronous - some may be synchronous.

Comment: observables can never be syncronous, their callback will always be asyncronous, thats the whole reason we define a callback.

Comment: Disagree, please check out this simple code on codesandbox (make sure to open the console): https://codesandbox.io/s/synchronous-rxjs-qjfs0k?file=/src/index.ts

But I agree that one should never relay on this behavior.

Comment: ok let me edit the answer. thanks for adding to my knowledge. i read more here :- https://christianlydemann.com/are-observables-async/

Comment: @AakashGarg I tried your solution but it still sends back undefined... any other suggestions?

Comment: try to print complete params?

Comment: @AakashGarg pls check the edit on the post

Comment: @CrackkiiCrazy url from which you are trying to get groupId?

Comment: @AakashGarg URL is:  http://localhost:4200/login?groupId=fun

Answer (score 1):

You subscribe an observable and they are asynchronous and your if condition outside the subscribe method so when you access your **groupId** propery you get undefined. you should access it in subscribe method.

```js
ngOnInit() {
     this.activeRoute.queryParams
    .subscribe(params => {
      this.groupId = params.groupId;
      console.log(this.groupId);
      if (this.groupId === undefined) {
         this.router.navigate(['/login/locked']);
      }

   })   
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Call to `this.activeRoute.queryParams.subscribe` is not synchronous, therefore console.log keeps reporting `undefined`. Add this check inside `subscribe`, like so:

```
this.activeRoute.queryParams
 .subscribe(params => {
   this.groupId = params.groupId;
   console.log(this.groupId);
   if (this.groupId === undefined) {
     this.router.navigate(['/login/locked']);
   }
})
```

Also, you may like to check Guards - that's something you might need: https://angular.io/guide/router-tutorial-toh#milestone-5-route-guards . By adding CanActivate guard which returns true or URL tree, you'll achieve what you want.